# Can't add content to mysql via jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Hi there am a beginner in php and ajax, was trying to create a simple admin page which only submit a message and the message get stored in a mysql database. (via ajax ) however it seems that the no data is being parse through when I hit the submit button(I coded it so that when the submit button is pressed, the message would be send without the page refreshing).

Could someone check to see where my error could be? thank you

admin.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <!--inseart script here -->
    <script type= "text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
    Message: <input type="text" name="message" id= "message_form"><br>      


    <input type="submit" id= "submit_form" onclick = "submit_msg()">


    <script type= "text/javascript" src="js/func_submit_msg.js">     </script> 
</body>

</html>
```

I have created a separate function file called func_submit_msg.js

```
//this is a function file to submit message to database

$(document).ready(function submit_msg(){
alert('worked');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit_data.php"
    data: { message: message_form},
})
}
```

a connect.php file is created to connect to mysql database

```
<?php

        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $pass = ""; // phpMyAdmin mysql password is blank ? i believe

        $database_name = "test"; //
        $table_name = "test_table_1";  //table that will be accessing

        //connect to mysql database
        $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database_name); 

        //check connection? 
        if ($db -> connect_error) {
            die("error mysql database not connected: " . $db -> connect_error);
        }
        else {
            echo "connected successfully" ; 
        }

?>
```

a submit_data.php file is created to submit to database

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

$insert_data=$db-> query ("INSERT INTO test_table_1(message) VALUES ('$message_form')");


if ($db->query($insert_data === TRUE) ){
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $insert_data . "<br>" . $cdb->error;
}

$db->close();

?>
```

error checking code to check whether database was inserted correctly doesn't even echo out whether it is successful or not.

Updated

submit_data.php as per @ Maximus2012 suggestion

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

$insert_data=$db->query("INSERT INTO test_table_1(message) VALUES ($_POST['message_form'])");


if ($insert_data === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $insert_data . "<br>" . $cdb->error;
}

$db->close();
```

?>

No error display but there isn't any data being recorded in the database still.

Comment: Try $_POST['message_form'] in place of $message_form in the insert query in submit.php. This may not be entirely secure though.

Comment: Also, in your code, you are calling the query function twice while you need to do that only once in submit.php. $insert_data=$db-> query (" should be $insert_data=$db->query(" (remove extra spaces)

Comment: @Maximus2012 what do you mean by calling it twice? i thought i had to do it as one of them is to insert a table the other is doing an error checking?

Comment: if ($db->query($insert_data === TRUE) ){ should be if ($insert_data === TRUE){ . You don't need to call the query function twice like this.

Comment: @Maximus2012 do i replace ('$message_form') with ('$_POST['message_form']? but wouldn't the func_submit_msg.js handle the "post" type hence $_POST is not needed again?

Comment: Yes. You have to replace it unless you have register globals turned on on your server which is not a secure practice anyway. $_POST[''] on the receiving PHP end will always give you correct result since PHP code does not care where the POST request is coming from. Which means you always need to have correct syntax on the PHP end.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: @Maximus2012 before changing my code, i tested the submit_data.php only.
this would be the error i receive on my browser

    connected successfully 
Notice: Undefined variable: message_form in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fyp/submit_data.php on line 4
New record created successfully

so it created a blank entry in the database,

Comment: @Maximus2012 however after using your $_POST method, i get this error

your code suggestion:

    $insert_data=$db-> query ("INSERT INTO test_table_1(message) VALUES ($_POST['message_form'])");

Error i receive:

    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fyp/submit_data.php on line 4

Comment: $insert_data=$db-> query ("INSERT  should be $insert_data=$db->query("INSERT . Remove the extra spaces.

Comment: @tadman could you give me an example on what you mean by parameterised my queries?

Comment: @peekaboo don't worry about that part yet. Get the basic code working first.

Comment: @Maximus2012 i did the changes as you suggested but I'm still not getting anything posted to my database. so not so sure what wrong  with it still.

Comment: You need to update your question with what you have tried so far and what part of the code is not working along with any error message that you might be getting.

Comment: @peekaboo There are many examples in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Parameters help clean up your query and keep it way more readable, plus make SQL injection bugs a non-issue. Throwing `$_POST` data into your query directly is extremely reckless and it will choke on even the smallest bit of irregular content like `It's okay.`. You'll find parameters are the easiest way to get this right every time instead of by chance.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I just did

Comment: and even tried @M.Doye method but it doesn't seem to work, even the error reporting he suggested (success ajax callback) doesn't seem to show up (doesn't show whether it is a success or not)

Comment: You still have spaces in your $db->query function call even after the update.

Comment: @Maximus2012 sorry bout that but ya updated on that one. still no difference

Comment: Try adding var_dump($_POST); exit(); right before your insert query and see what you get.

Comment: @Maximus2012
running the admin.php , nothing is being stored in the database
when running the submit_data.php only this is the error message i get : 

    connected successfully 
Notice: Undefined index: message in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fyp/submit_data.php on line 4
array(0) { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by adding your `success` callback to your Ajax: (if you havent already)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#submit_form').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    message_form = $('#message_form').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit_data.php",
        data: {message: message_form},
            success: function(data) {
              $('#result').html(data);
            },
            error:function(err){
               //handle your error
               alert('did not work');
            }
    });
  });
});
```

- Here we use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) as the preferred method of attaching an
  event handler function
- We then use [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the message input field
  and store it in a variable to be used for POSTing to the submit_data.php script
- `e.preventDefault()` is used so that the default event is cancelled
  when click the submit button

---

In your html, add an element that the result can be returned to: (`#result`)

```
<html>
<head> 
    <script type= "text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type= "text/javascript" src="js/func_submit_msg.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    Message: <input type="text" name="message" id="message_form"><br>      

    <input type="submit" id="submit_form">
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

- Here we wrap your input in a form with the `method` and `action`
  properties to ensure that the name attributes are able to be used in
  POST requests

---

In your PHP (submit_data.php) you need to assign a value to `$message_form` before using it:

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

$message_form = $_POST['message'];

$insert_data=$db->query("INSERT INTO test_table_1(message) VALUES ('$message_form')");


if ($insert_data === TRUE ){
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $insert_data . "<br>" . $cdb->error;
  }

$db->close();
?>
```

If all goes well, you should get *some kind* of result from this.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work, and it seems that the <div> id=result doesn't display anything .whether it was successful or not

Comment: I believe the submit_data.php file is working fine now as it can create blank entry when run by itself, so it seems that the ajax function that is parsing data to the submit_data.php doesn't seem to work as it should

Comment: I have changed the Ajax and HTML. Try it this way, without the `onclick="..."` and with the inputs wrapped in a `<form>` to make sure your data gets posted

Comment: M.doye sorry it works now, the ajax file that i had was different. thanks a lot . by the way what does this mean in your ajax file 
 function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

why did you put e inside it? i saw this in a few examples when i googled but never understood

Comment: thanks for your help

would like to also ask why did you not use onclick ? and wrap it around as a form?